# What's the correct way to use a unix domain socket in requests framework?

Tags: python, python-requests

Usually, doing a post request using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) framework is done by:

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

But: How do I connect to a unix socket instead of doing a TCP connection?

On a related note, how to encode domain path in the URL?

- libcurl allows application to supply own socket on which to perform request
- LDAP invented own scheme `ldapi` where socket name is %-encoded in host field
- `httpie` uses `http+unix` scheme and %-encoded path in host field

These are some examples, but is there an RFC or established best practice?

Comment: A socket is a file descriptor.  You read/write the descriptor.  I do not think I get what you want.

Comment: Yes, also non-unix sockets are descriptors. But this is not a low-level implementation but an HTTP client.

Comment: requests is an HTTP library. If you write an adapter you can control how the connection is created. That said, it doesn't appear as if cURL supports this, so do not expect requests to go out of their way to add ways to support this for you

Comment: @Kevin many services do, for example MySQL. It's a small step to services that use HTTP. Besides several server frameworks support unix domain sockets, e.g. cherrypy, flask, gunicorn. The main advantage is UNIX security model in multiuser environment where server process is not privileged.

Comment: @Kevin think on other type of servers, like an inner local server mounted with Tornado serving a proxiable outwards interface, and a unix socket interface for inner, control logic/commands

Answer (score 28):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel:

https://github.com/msabramo/requests-unixsocket

URL scheme is `http+unix` and socket path is percent-encoded into the host field:

```
import requests_unixsocket

session = requests_unixsocket.Session()

# Access /path/to/page from /tmp/profilesvc.sock
r = session.get('http+unix://%2Ftmp%2Fprofilesvc.sock/path/to/page')
assert r.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Or to interact with Docker's socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`), use a URL like `http+unix://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/info`

Comment: By the way, there is also a plugin for [HTTPie](https://httpie.org/) to interact with unix domain sockets: https://github.com/msabramo/httpie-unixsocket

Comment: Could you please elaborate why we need to specify separators as `%2F` ?

Comment: Because two things with slashes have to be stashed into the URL: the file path and the URL path. The file path is escaped and becomes the host part of the URL.

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking for a minimalistic and clean approach to this in Python 3, here's a working example that will talk to Ubuntu's snapd on a unix domain socket.

```py
import requests
import socket
import pprint

from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection
from urllib3.connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter


class SnapdConnection(HTTPConnection):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("localhost")

    def connect(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect("/run/snapd.socket")


class SnapdConnectionPool(HTTPConnectionPool):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("localhost")

    def _new_conn(self):
        return SnapdConnection()


class SnapdAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def get_connection(self, url, proxies=None):
        return SnapdConnectionPool()


session = requests.Session()
session.mount("http://snapd/", SnapdAdapter())
response = session.get("http://snapd/v2/system-info")
pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

Comment: Hi, Nice code, would you please tell me how we can handle exceptions with your code

Comment: Is it not required to close the socket after opening it in `connect`?

Comment: @AnupamGhosh it would be more correct to add an override to the HttpConnection subclass for the close() method that does that. However, sockets are automatically closed when garbage collected – so the answer is no, it is not required.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to create a TCP to UNIX socket proxy, something like:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/tmp/foo.sock
```

And then send your http requests to that proxy. The server listening on UNIX socket `/tmp/foo.sock` still has to understand HTTP because `socat` does not do any message conversion.

Answer (score 2):

*requests* has no implementation to work with unix sockets out-of-the-box.

But you can create custom [adapter](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) that will connect to unix socket, send request and read answer.

All methods you need to implement are `.send()` and `.close()`, that's easy and straightforward.

After registering the adapter in session object you can use *requests* machinery with UNIX transport.

Comment: Also, in case of DIY, I think it's easier to subclass and add own connection pool. Only getting a new connection needs to be changed in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105249/luis-masuelli is to use the `httpx` package instead,

```
>>> import httpx
>>> # Define a transporter
>>> transport = httpx.HTTPTransport(uds="/tmp/profilesvc.sock")
>>> client = httpx.Client(transport=transport)
>>> response = client.get('http://path/to/page')
>>> assert response.status_code == 200
```