# What is the correct way to specify the URL scheme to a UNIX socket?

Tags: bash, sockets, unix, url

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27268999/13442245) on stackoverflow says that the right way to specify the URL to a UNIX socket is by using the format `http+unix://%2Ftmp%2Fprofilesvc.sock/path/to/page` where the scheme is `http+unix`. However, [this website](https://dev.solita.fi/2021/12/21/docker-on-wsl2-without-docker-desktop.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9Cdocker%20%2DH%20unix%3A///mnt/wsl/shared%2Ddocker/docker.sock%20run%20%2D%2Drm%20hello%2Dworld%E2%80%9D) suggests the right way is to use the format `unix:///mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock`, where the scheme is `unix`. I'm simply confused as to which is the correct way and if both are correct, how they are different. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The second form applies to a Docker instance.

Comment: @user207421 is it just a syntax that Docker uses? Is `http+unix` the standard way to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first form isn't standard (it's specific to that library), and no standard Unix Domain Socket URI exists.

Comment: @Hasturkun that clears it up.